# angular ui-router not opening main view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a set up like so:

broadband_safety.html:

```
<div ui-view></div>

<div ng-include="'content/secondary_nav.html'"></div>
```

And the routes I have set up are:

```
.state('broadband_safety', {
    url: '/broadband_safety',
    templateUrl: './content/broadband_safety.html'
})

.state('broadband_safety.what_is_sbs', {
        url: '/what_is_sbs',
        templateUrl: './content/what_is_sbs.html'
    })
```

So lets say I navigate to broadband_safety. What I get is a blank ui-view, and the navigation bar at the bottom. What I want, is to load a page when you navigate to broadband_safety. Im sure its simple, but for the life of me i cant figure it out.

The second state is the first button in the navigation bar. I would like that page to load when i navigate to broadband_safety.html.. I have tried changing the broadband template to what_is_sbs, but then the navigation bar dissapears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue.

To solve this, I used:

```
.state('broadband_safety', {
    **abstract: true,**
    url: '/broadband_safety',
    templateUrl: './content/broadband_safety.html'
})
```

and then:

```
.state('broadband_safety.home', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: './content/what_is_sbs.html'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This should have double dots:

```
templateUrl: 'content/broadband_safety.html'
```

You will need to go back up one directory.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but single or double dots, its still does not make a difference. When I navigate to broadband_safety.html, i get a blank ui-view, and a navigation bar underneath it.

Comment: Ok. Then try without the ./

Comment: I dont see a change?

Comment: I can navigate to the ui-view just fine, i just get a blank ui-view. What i need to know is how to load a template into the parent ui-view when you navigate to it.